# Need Json Response to be queried and bind to modal view

Tags: json, linq, model-view-controller

json response

```
[
    {
        "name": "Bob",
        "gender": "Male",
        "age": 23,
        "pets": [
            {
                "name": "Garfield",
                "type": "Cat"
            },
            {
                "name": "Fido",
                "type": "Dog"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Jennifer",
        "gender": "Female",
        "age": 18,
        "pets": [
            {
                "name": "Garfield",
                "type": "Cat"
                "name": "sam",
                "type": "dog"
            }
        ]
    },
```

I need to query and find the records with two list each for male and female with there pets who are only cat
so out put would be

```
Male
garfield 
female 
garfield
```

Comment: You need this. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/json-serialization-and-deserialization-in-c-sharp/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) as follow:

```
var root = JToken.Parse(json);

var values = root.Select(t => new
{
    Name = t.SelectToken("pets").FirstOrDefault(p => p.Value<string>("type") == "Cat")["name"],
    Gender = t["gender"].ToString()
});
```

See: https://dotnetfiddle.net/1zoJaw

Result:

```
Name : Garfield, Gender :Male
Name : Garfield, Gender :Female
```

Answer (score 0):

Install a package that reads Json.

In visual studio: right click references; manage nuget packages; Find NewtonSoft.Json; install.

You need a function that reads your file and returns an `IEnumerable<PetOwner>`.
Read the NewtonSoft manual about how to do this.

```
public static IEnumerable<PetOwner> ReadPetOwners(string fileName) {...}
```

> I need to query and find the records with two list each for male and female with their pets who are only cat

So you don't want (some properties of ) PetOwners that has only Cats, you want the gender of PetOwners, each with the names of their Cats.

```
IEnumerable<PetOwner> petOwners = ReadPetOwners("PetOwners.Json");
var result = petOwners.Select(petOwner => new
{
    Gender = petOwner.Gender,

    Cats = petOwner.Pets.Where(pet => pet.Type == "Cat")
                        .Select(pet => pet.Name)
                        .ToList(),
});
```

In words: take the sequence of PetOwners. From every PetOwner in this sequence, make one new object with two properties. Property `Gender` contains the Gender of the PetOwner. Property `Cats` contains the names of the zero or more Cats of this PetOwner.

To fill property Cats, take the Pets of this CatOwner. Keep only those Pets that have type Cat. From the remaining Pets, take the Name and put everything in a List.

Trouble is: you will also have the genders of the PetOwners that have no Cats at all. If you don't want them. Filter them using a `Where`.

Continue the LINQ:

```
.Where(petOwner => petOwner.Cats.Any());
```

Simple comme bonjour

Comment: Thanks guys you answer looks good to me , by the time i have done something in UI for filtration to achieve the result , and i was susscessfull ,

Comment: But your answers looks good to me in a sense the querying should be done in code then view .